# how to update a table from a file having decimal field?

Tags: db2, cobol

i'm writing a cobol program to read a PS file and update a DB2 table based on the flag set in the PS file. One of the fields in the file is declared as a decimal field in the cobol program. But when i try to update that field in the table,its showing error. What should i declare the same field in the table and how should i write the update statement for the field?

The field name is salary which has a decimal point.

Comment: An the error is ...? and the column in DB2 is ...? And the pic in cobol is ...?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much more helpful if you were to post the PICTURE/USAGE clauses for
the data item in your input file record as well as the DB/2 column definition.

However, this looks a lot like a data conversion issue. Things to check out are:

- Does the input file record have a PICTURE/USAGE something like `PIC 9(5).99`. The key point
  is that there is an explicit decimal point in the declaration. If you look at the
  input file with a text editor (eg. the ISPF editor) you would see a number something
  like `12345.67`. These numbers are in display format. Think of them as being text.
- DB/2 column definition. Decimal numbers in DB/2 are commonly declared as something like:
  `DECIMAL(7,2)`. Numbers declared in this way are stored by DB/2 in packed decimal
  format.

Display format numbers, as probably exist in the input file, are not compatible with
Packed Decimal numbers (apples and oranges).

To illustrate this point consider the following little COBOL program:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                          
PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.                              
DATA DIVISION.                                    
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                          
01  A                  PIC 9(6).99.               
01  B                  PIC 9(6)V99 PACKED-DECIMAL.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                               
    MOVE 123456.78 TO A                           
    DISPLAY 'A=' A                                
    MOVE A TO B                                   
    ADD 1 TO B                                    
    DISPLAY 'B=' B                                
    MOVE B TO A                                   
    DISPLAY 'A=' A                                
    GOBACK.
```

Variable `A` is in display format, with an explicit decimal point. All you can do
is assign it a value for display purposes. Trying to do something like `ADD 1 TO A` will result
in a compile error.

The trick is to get numbers in display format into something that is a compatible with DB/2 (eg. Packed Decimal). 
The COBOL MOVE verb does this job. Declare a new variable with a data type compatible
to that used by DB/2. Variable `B` above is such a variable. Move the display 
formatted variable to the Packed Decimal variable as in: `MOVE A TO B`. The COBOL run-time does this conversion.

Notice that you can now add something to `B`. Display `B` (woops the decimal point disappeared -
I will let you figure out why). Then move it back to display format, hey, the decimal point
came back.

DB/2 takes host variables as they come without conversion. If that host variable does not have the
correct data format you will get an error.

You probably need to do something like:

```
  Read Record
  MOVE record display data (eg. `A`) to a DB/2 compatible field (eg. `B`)
  EXEC SQL
     INSERT INTO table (
         ...
         SALARY,
         ...)
       VALUES (
         ...
         :B,
         ...)
  END-EXEC.
```

Answer (score 0):

The decimal field type holds the value in a format which is not compatible with DB2 and needs to be converted before releasing the new value to the database (assuming you have write or update permissions for the record). You may need to move it to a PIC 9(6)V.99 field or similar then update the DB2 record. COBOL is a programming language with different data representaions for manipulation while the database is for storing away the data in a record and may have less formats available.